# trouble with php getimagesize (url encode problems with space)

Tags: php, getimagesize

I use `getimagesize` to judge an image height and size.

When a url has space, the `getimagesize` echo's an error. I've tried using `urlencode()` to transfer all the url address, it still returns an error. I noticed that if I just change the space into `%20`, `getimagesize` runs ok.

I have no idea why?

I also tired to  use `$newurl = preg_replace(' ', '%20', $url);` It echo'ed :

```
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Empty regular expression
```

So how to *`preg_replace`* correctly. And is there a way to transfer the url correctly with `getimagesize` so that it passes all possible test cases.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `str_replace(' ', "%20", $url)` instead of `preg_replace(' ', '%20', $url);`

Answer (score 3):

`urldecode()` is the function you want to use to decode all those characters back after you've converted them before processing the image. Run the string containing the URL through that.

Answer (score 2):

If only the file name contains spaces you can use rawurlencode().

```
$url = dirname($url) . '/'. rawurlencode(basename($url));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some example code from when you tried to use urlencode?  Also, you don't need to use preg_replace for the last bit, you can simply use str_replace.